# comments in laravel using ajax

Tags: php, json, ajax, laravel

```
public function store(Request $request, $id)
{
    $request->validate([

        'body' => 'required',
    ]);

    $article = Article::where('id', $id)->firstOrFail();

    $comment = new Comment();
    $comment->body = $request->input('body');
    $comment->user_id = Auth::id();
    $comment->article()->associate($article);


    $comment->save($request->all());

    $comment->user;
    return response()->json($comment);
    }

<script>
    $("#comment").submit(function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        var body = $("#body").val()
        var _token = $('input[name="_token"]').val();
        $.ajax({
            method: "POST",
            url: "{{route('pages.comments.store', $article->id)}}",
            dataType: "json",
            data: {
                _token:_token, body: body
            },
            success: function(data, status, xhr){
                $("#body").val("");
                alert("comment added successfully");
                $('.comment-list').append(
                    `<li class="comment">
                        <div class="vcard bio">
                            <img src="{{asset('uploads/profilepics')}}/${data.user.image}" alt="${data.user.image}" class="img-circle">
                        </div>
                        <div class="comment-body">
                            <h3>${data.user.name}</h3>
                            <div class="meta">${data.created_at}</div>
                            <p id="display">${data.body}</p>
                        </div>
                    </li>`
                );
            },
            error: function(xhr, status, error){
                console.log(error);
                alert("something went wrong");
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

i have comments system with laravel with ajax and all fine without refreshing, but the method i use to show how many comments can't make it +1 evrytime comment added except refreshing, so how to do it ?

#### {{$comment->user->name}}

Comment: you need to get the count and update that with the ajax request as well, i would prefer using vuejs with laravel, it just makes things easier.

Comment: don't know vuejs, all i want is grab the element and make count +1 everytime in success function, but don't know how!!

Comment: you can count the number of elements (comments) in the `div` tag and display it there, whenever you make the Ajax call.

Comment: tried many times, but can't
all i can is one ajax call then counter stops again

Comment: Can you please write your controller code for route('pages.comments.store')??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can count all comments that belongs to your article in your controller and then you pass it to view:

```
public function store(Request $request, $id) {
        $request->validate([ 'body' => 'required', ]);
        $article = Article::where('id', $id)->firstOrFail();
        $comment = new Comment();
        $comment->body = $request->input('body');
        $comment->user_id = Auth::id();
        $comment->article()->associate($article);
        $comment->save($request->all());

        $count = count(Comment::where('article_id',$id)->get());
        $comment->count = $count; 

        return response()->json($comment);
    }
```

and in your view in ajax success you can update your count

Comment: thanks it worked, all i thought was in ajax in view and forget about controller
thanks